# Validate that multiple Prompts have a value

Tags: javascript, validation, alert

1. I´m trying to write a simple test where I ask for name and age in separate      Prompts. I´d like to validate user really adds a value in both prompts. 
   What´s the best way to do this validation without duplicating code? 
   When I click "OK" with no value, it does not ask me to add a value

   ```
   function showInfo() {
   //Asking for name in a prompt
   var name = prompt("Name: ","");
   //Checking if it is null or empty
   if (name == null || ""){alert("Please enter your name");}
   //Same for age
   var age = prompt("Age: ","");
   if (age == null || ""){alert("Please enter your age.");}
   }
   ```
2. Also, noticed that "null" is to check the "Cancel" button, but I was able to test that if you click "Cancel", and click "Cancel" again, it does not ask for a value. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: `age == null || ""` parses as `(age == null) || ""`.

Comment: Your question is little unclear, do you want to show `prompt` again if user enters no value and click OK?

Comment: @Katherine: Check below solution I posted and accept the answer if it helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put it in a loop to ask again. Here I'm using `!name` to check for the
"truthyness" of `name`. `null` and an empty string are both "falsy" so, `!name`
will return `true` for them, a non-empty string is truthy, so `!name` will
return `false` for them.

```js
function ask (msg, errMsg) {
  var name;
  do {
    name = prompt(msg);
    //Checking if it is null or empty
    if (!name) {
      alert(errMsg);
    }
    
  } while (!name);
  return name;
}

function showInfo() {
  var name,
    age;
  name = ask("Name:", "Please enter your name");
  age = ask("Age:", "Please enter your age.");
}

showInfo();
```

That said, unless this is just a prototype or a small personal project only you
will use, **don't do it this way!** Sticking the user in a loop prompt will
frustrate most people. Most modern browsers include a "Don't show me this again"
check box. I'm not sure what would happen if the user checks it, the browser
might continue in an infinite loop and lock up or crash.

Instead it would be better to do it with a form on the page:

```js
var elShowInfo = document.getElementById('show-info'),
  elName = document.getElementById('name'),
  elAge = document.getElementById('age'),
  elOut = document.getElementById('output');

function showInfo (ev) {
  // stop the form from submitting
  ev.preventDefault();
  
  var name = elName.value,
    age = elAge.value;
  if (name && age) {
    // do something with name/age
    elOut.textContent = name + ' is ' + age + ' years old.';
  }
}

elShowInfo.addEventListener('click', showInfo, false);
```

```html
<form>
<label for="name">Name:</label> <input id="name" placeholder="Please enter your name">
<label for="age">Age:</label> <input id="age" placeholder="Please enter your age">
<button id="show-info">Show info</button>
</form>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Every time the Show Info button is pressed it checks for the data once and then does something with it if it is there; otherwise it does nothing.

One thing to note, both `prompt` and the `.value` property of an element return strings so if you are going to use `age` to do some sort of calculation you will need to convert it to a number either using [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), `age = parseInt(age, 10)` or an [unary +](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus), `age = +age;`.

Further reading:

- [Truthy and Falsy: When All is Not Equal in JavaScript](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/)
- [Introduction to the DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction)

Comment: @Katherine Glad to hear it helped! Up votes for helpful answers are always appreciated ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You if condition is wrong. You should use

```
if (name === null || name === "") {
  //you code here
}
```

**And If you like to show `prompt` continusly unless user enters input below code will work:**

```js
function showInfo() {

while(1) {
 //Asking for name in a prompt
 var name = prompt("Name: ","");
 if (name === null || name === ""){alert("Please enter your name");}
 else break;
}

console.log("Name= "+name);


while(1) {
 //Same for age
 var age = prompt("Age: ","");
 //Checking if it is null or empty
 if (age === null || age === ""){alert("Please enter your age.");}
 else break;
}
console.log("Age ="+age);
}
showInfo();
```

Answer (score 0):

@Arshad answer adds more clarity.

on a side note, the reason why the || didn't work is the order of evaluation.

```
 if (age == null || "") --> evaluated as 
 if ((age == null) || "") --> true on Cancel, false on Ok
```

Hope this helps !